# angular directives comment section

Tags: angularjs

I am working on a website that displays numerous articles.  Each article has a comment section.  I have effectively been able to recursively write the comments to the DOM with recursion inside an ng-repeat.  However, I need to be able to click on a respond button on any of the comments (they display in a nested fashion) and for a div to be inserted beneath the clicked button.  This div would contain a text area for the comment they want to submit and a button.  When this second button is clicked, the controller will save the comment to the database. I initially wanted to do this by directly manipulating the DOM from the controller.  However, after further research, that would be in direct violation of the MVC/MVW pattern.  I believe the correct answer is to create a custom directive.  Please give me some insight on how to correctly do this.  Any and all information would be very helpful.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add response div dinamically:

```
<div ng-repeat="article in articles" id="article-{{$index}}">
  <p>{{article.content}}</p>
  <button ng-click="addAnswer($index)">Add Answer</button>
</div>
```

js:

```
myApp.controller("articlesController", function($compile){
  $scope.addAnswer = function (index) {
     var div = $("<div></div>");
     var input = $("<input type='text' ng-model='article.response'></input>");
     div.append(input);
     var button = $("<button>Send</button>");
     button.attr("ng-click", "sendResponse(article)");
     $compile(div)($scope);
     $("#article-" + index).append(div);
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to make a directive to achieve this.

html:

```
<div ng-repeat="article in articles">
  <p>{{article.content}}</p>
  <input type="text" ng-model="article.response"></input>
  <button ng-click="sendResponse(article)">Send</button>
</div>
```

js:

```
myApp.controller("articlesController", function($http){

  $scope.sendResponse = function (article) {
    console.log(article.response);
    $http.post(url, article);
  };
});
```

Of course, you can do it better by hidding input and send button, and show it after user clicks over an answer button.

Comment: OK.  So your suggestion is to add the response div to every comment and only show it when a user clicks on respond?

Comment: Yes, it is. Or maybe you can add this dinamically, but you will need to compile new html tags.